# Return value from php top level php script gets swallowed

Tags: php, return-value, router

I am hunting a bug in an application which I could narrow down to a required return value not getting returned as a result of a http request to an http server. The request is a POST uploading a file, the return value should be a confirmation in form of a string that can be used to access that file later.

The server is running a php script to process the uploaded file, all works fine, except I do not get that required string in the return payload. Instead the payload is empty.

The problem is caused be an additional request router I implemented on top of the existing application. The router is a simple top-level script (index.php) which is directly called by the http server (apache2) as a result of some rewriting based routing on server level.

Here is the (reduced and simplyfied) router script. For the test case it is called with these values: `service=put&method=logo`. As expected it includes the file `...../service/pi.php` which does some processing and terminates correctly returning the required string:

```
<?php

require_once \CONFIG\PATH\BACKEND.'/include/exception.php';

try {

  $service = isset($_GET['service']) ? $_GET['service'] : (isset($_POST['service']) ? $_POST['service'] : NULL);
  $method  = isset($_GET['method'])  ? $_GET['method']  : (isset($_POST['method'])  ? $_POST['method']  : NULL);

  switch ($service) {
    case 'amf':         return include \CONFIG\PATH\BACKEND.'/service/amf.php';
    case 'bof':         return include \CONFIG\PATH\BACKEND.'/service/bof.php';
    case 'put':
      switch ($method) {
        case 'deco':
        case 'img':
        case 'logo':
        case 'plan':    $ret = include \CONFIG\PATH\BACKEND.'/service/pi.php';
                        error_log('+++ '.print_r($ret,true));
                        error_log('*** '.print_r(debug_backtrace(),true));
                        echo "honkitonk";
                        return $ret;
        default:        throw new \PDExceptionLogicalError('Invalid method');
      } // switch method
    case 'get':
      switch ($method) {
        case 'creport': return include \CONFIG\PATH\BACKEND.'/service/gcr.php';
        case 'deco':    return include \CONFIG\PATH\BACKEND.'/service/gdi.php';
        case 'img':     return include \CONFIG\PATH\BACKEND.'/service/gi.php';
        case 'report':  return include \CONFIG\PATH\BACKEND.'/service/gr.php';
        default:        throw new \PDExceptionLogicalError('Invalid method');
      } // switch method
    default:            throw new \PDExceptionLogicalError('Invalid service');
  } // switch service

} catch (PDException $e) { return $e->getPDError(); }

?>
```

The output in the log files is generated for test purposes only. Normally that branch of the two switch statements would simply return the result of the included script jsut like it is done in the other branches.

The resulting payload sent back to the client is valid and contains the test string "honkitonk", but *not* the return value in `$ret`. The script execution does *not* continue behind the switch statement or anything, the script is terminated with the `return $ret;` inside the questionable inner switch branch.

The output in the log file shows this:

```
[Sat Sep 28 09:17:39 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] +++ /backend/get?method=img&id=26
[Sat Sep 28 09:17:39 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] *** Array\n(\n)\n
```

The empty array in the log file (result of the `debug_backtrace()` call proves that the script is on top level. A return in a top level script should result in the return value to be handed over into the server reply. However this is not the case here. And I simply do not understand why!

I also made a check using a global output puffer around the script and examining that: exctly the same result: "honkitonk", but not the required string value in `$ret`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I suggest you change the code in pi.php (and the others) to a function, load the file with those functions and call the function. This will give you a cleaner code you can debug.

Answer (score -1):

Just a quick guess, put ( and ) around your include statements:

Return ( include 'file' );

Does the included file contains a return statement or do you just print the contents you want?

Comment: Sorry, that was not precise: the included files obviously _return_ the result string.

Comment: I don't get the idea behind your suggestion: the switch branch in question here is that one with `$ret = include \CONFIG\PATH\BACKEND.'/service/pi.php';`. `$ret` contains the expected return value as proven by the debug output. That cannot be the problem.

Comment: True, but my point was adding the ( and ) for getting the return value of the file. So meaning you use $x = ( include('file'));

Comment: Sorry, but there is absolutely no reason for this. As said before: `$ret` _does_ contain the value. That is _not_ the problem!

Comment: When changing the return to an echo and adding an empty return?

Comment: Yes, of course the output works when I echo the results of the include instead of eturning`it. This is what I demonstrated with the test string "honkitonk". Please note that I ask _why_ my code does not work. According to my experience and the documentation of `return` the strategy _should_ work. I fail to understand why it does _not_ work. This is why I ask. Check the documentation of phps `return` statement: a return on top level outputs the return value into the reply. Usually that works. Why not here?